# SQL Server 2012 Not matching Join Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have to generate a query output for not matching records.

Assuming that i have two tables Table1 and Table2.  Both Tables have the columns as DrugName.  No Id column. Just the value column.

I have to generate an output from Table1 by filtering DrugNames which are in Table2.  Assuming, Table1 has 1000 records and Table2 has 100 records. On applying filter, i should get 900 records from Table1.

```
select * from Table1
left join Table2 on
Table1.DrugName = Table2.DrugName
where Table2.DrugName is null
```

Above syntax returns non matching records.

Let's say in Table2.DrugName will be "ABCD" while in Table1.DrugName will be either "XYZ ABCD" or "ABCD GHIJ". If Table1.DrugName has matching word "%ABCD%", I have to filter.

Comment: It looks like the relationship between those two tables is foggy at best.  How flexible is the current structure?

Comment: How did this question get upvoted?! The requirements are so unclear

Comment: Can you provide sample output? Joining on something that "doesn't match" is kind of meaningless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Select * from Table1
Left Join Table2
on Table1.DrugName LIKE '%' + Table2.DrugName + '%'
```

...but bear in mind that performance could be awful. You might be better off splitting the longer names into parts, and then joining on the DrugNameElements table. That way, you can index the elements and quickly identify the matching ones.

Comment: isn't this "like" will return matching records? I guess OP is looking for non matching records.

Comment: I took it to mean inexact matches, rather than complete non-matches. He describes having VICKS in one and ACTION VICKS 500 in the other.

Comment: @Robfarley, Thanks. That query returns matching record right. Though, havent tried. I am looking for NON Matching records. My join syntax could be a wrong approach. I can use either NOT EXIST or ROW_NUMBER PARTITION OVER BY something like that

Comment: If Rob's query gives you the matching rows and you want the rest (non-matching rows), add `WHERE Table2.DrugName IS NULL;`

Comment: @goofyui, so my comment is right. Farley's query gives the records for matching rows. You can use same query by altering "LIKE" operator to "NOT LIKE" operator.

Comment: Thank you Anup Shah.Yes your comment is right